# ASP.NET Table Data Editor

Tags: c#, asp.net, nhibernate, gridview

I want to create a control to enable me to edit the data from a table.
I want something similar to the `Edit top 200 rows` from `SQL Server Management Studio`.
The ideea is that I have some coefficient tables and the user that hadles these must be able to modify the coefficients.

I have found a probable solution here http://www.highoncoding.com/ArticleDetails.aspx?articleID=139, but I want to see some other options.

I am also using `nHibernate` with `SqlServer 2008`

Should I simply use the `GridView`, a `Repeater` or are there any other good options ?

Answer (score 0):

What's your budget?

The Telerik Grid editor is very good,  if you can afford it.  The Telerik MVC grid editor is also reasonably good and free.

If you can use MVC also look at the new MVC3 scaffolding package which you can download via NuGet.

Ultimately most grid solutions will do this job - as that's exactly what they are for.  So you need to look at specific features,  costs,  which platform they support in order to narrow it down to the 'best' option.

One other word of advice.  The database / ORM layer shouldn't be a factor in the decision.  If it is then you're mixing your layers.

Comment: The budget for this is 0$. I am using web forms, and I cannot change to MVC.

Comment: I suspected that might be the case :)  There are lots of good free grid editors.  I do find that grid editors are the kind of thing developers love and non-developer users hate however.   Is there some reason you don't want to use GridView?  Justifying why anything else should be used instead is hard unless you can say what's wrong with the most obvious out of the box solution.

Comment: It's one of my first choices actually, I was just wandering if there is a better solution to this.